# Automata Editor

Tags: path-finding

I'm currently developing a State machine editor as a tool for some games my team is developing:

[image: overlapping]
[image: overlapping2]

but the algorithm I chose to display the paths between the states doesn't care about the obstacles, I'm totally lost on what's the topic I should be looking for because all I can find is how to find the shortest path between 2 nodes on a graph or the dijkstra algorithm,

there should be something simpler I just want it to look fancy, I do not want the shortest path or something of the sort.

Thanks.

Comment: For the boxes, some sort of collisiondetection will have to be done, for the lines using the bump the use in electrical scheme's would clear things up. just order your line-on-line intersection detection so only the first (or last) line added gets the bumpy thing